# How to continiously monitor Wiegand readers using pigpio library?

Tags: c, pigpio

How do I need to modify the C example from http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html for continious monitoring of Wiegand readers?

I need to run it as background process.

For now I have a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include "wiegand.h"


void callback1(int bits, uint32_t value)
{

    FILE *saved = stdout;
    stdout = fopen("log_readers.txt", "a");
    printf("Reader_1: bits=%d value=%u\n", bits, value);
    fclose(stdout);
    stdout = saved;
}

void callback2(int bits, uint32_t value)
{
   FILE *saved = stdout;
   stdout = fopen("log_readers.txt", "a");   
   printf("Reader_2: bits=%d value=%u\n", bits, value);
   fclose(stdout);
   stdout = saved;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Pi_Wieg_t * w1;
   Pi_Wieg_t * w2;
   if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 1;
   w1 = Pi_Wieg(14, 15, callback1, 5);
   w2 = Pi_Wieg(23, 24, callback2, 5);
   sleep(300);
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w1);
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w2);
   gpioTerminate();
}
```

After 5 minutes of execution it's terminated, I suppose cause of `sleep(300)`. If I wrap it by infinite loop like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    while(0) {
      Pi_Wieg_t * w1;
      ...
    }
}
```

it's terminated immediately after running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int done = 0;

   Pi_Wieg_t * w1;
   Pi_Wieg_t * w2;
   if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 1;
   w1 = Pi_Wieg(14, 15, callback1, 5);
   w2 = Pi_Wieg(23, 24, callback2, 5);
   while (!done)
   {
      sleep(1);

      /* add code here to detect the exit condition (if any)
         and set done = 1
      */
   }
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w1);
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w2);
   gpioTerminate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your infinite loop condition is wrong - `while (0)` is the same as `while false`, which means the loop never gets run. Change this to `while (1)` and you get an infinite loop.

Regarding the first code - since the main loop only has a `sleep(300)` in it, it will terminate as soon as the `sleep` is over, since you have your `Wieg_cancel` and `gpioTerminate` calls straight after this.

You might want to study up a bit on how to write programs in C, as the above issues are very trivial.